# How to Scatter Elements of a Ruby Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I have an array of elements, which have a common attribute and are sorted by this attribute. Now, I want to achieve the opposite effect: interleave elements with the same attribute value as much as possible.

```
[
  {a: 1},
  {a: 1},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 3},
  {a: 3},
  {a: 3},
  {a: 3},
].scatter_somehow


# =>
[
  {a: 3},
  {a: 1},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 3},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 1},
  {a: 3},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 3},
]
```

If there was the same number of elements for each value of `a`, I could have grouped them, then zipped the arrays and flattened the result. But `Array#zip` stops as soon as there are no elements in the smallest array.

How would I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How is your requirement different from [`Array#shuffle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle)?

Comment: Shuffle returns a randomly mixed array. I want the elements to be as distributed as possible.

Comment: @shock_one shouldn't `{a: 1}` be on first and last positions in the resulting array then?

Comment: @EugenePetrov: Good question. But this would move the initial `{a:3}`s closer to each other. A correct approach would start with defining a measure for the "distributedness" which has to be maximized. I understood a zip-based solution is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your initial approach is something like

```
x.group_by { | e | e[:a] }.values.inject(&:zip).flatten
```

It fails if a group has less elements than an earlier group.

The idea is to switch them if the first array is too short (afterwards remove the `nil`s with `compact`):

```
x.group_by { | e | e[:a] }.values.inject do | a, e |
  if a.length < e.length 
    e.zip(a)
  else
    a.zip(e)
  end
end.flatten.compact
```